# "Max storage size not supported" When Upgrading AWS RDS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I am using **db.m5.4xlarge** but our users increase lot so the server is going too slow, we want to upgrade RDS to **db.m5.8xlarge**, But when I try to upgrade RDS, it gave me an error (**Max storage size not supported**).

Comment: Are you making any other changes? Also are you using a single database? Is the database read heavy or write heavy?

Comment: No, I am not making any other changes. I am using a single Mysql Database there. Its Read heavy.

Comment: Any reason why you can't use read replicas? :)

Comment: No, I don't have any reason

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the reason is that, unlike `db.m5.4xlarge`, `db.m5.8xlarge` **does not support** MySQL. From [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/Concepts.DBInstanceClass.html):

[image]

Comment: So if I want to upgrade then I need to upgrade it to  db.m5.12xlarge ?

Comment: @RashedRaj The table says that db.m5.12xlarge supports mysql. But wouldn't read replicas be better as Chris suggested? Could be cheaper to have 2 x 4xlarge, then 1 12xlarge?

Comment: @RashedRaj No problem. But please  consider Chris suggestions for future if possible.

Comment: Yeah, Sure I am working to apply Chris suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

Judged on discussion with you I think it might actually be more beneficial for you to take a look at creating read replicas rather than an ever growing instance.

The problem with increasing the instance as you are are now is that everytime it will simply reach another bottleneck and it becomes a single point of failure.

Instead the following strategy is more appropriate and may end up saving you cost:

- Create [read replicas in RDS](https://aws.amazon.com/rds/features/read-replicas/) to handle all read only SQL queries, by doing this you are going to see performance gains over your current handling. You might even be able to scale down the write cluster.
- As your application is read heavy look at using caching for your applications to avoid heavy read usage. AWS provides [ElastiCache](https://aws.amazon.com/elasticache/) a a managed service using either [Redis](https://aws.amazon.com/elasticache/redis/) or [MemcacheD](https://aws.amazon.com/elasticache/memcached) as the caching service. This again could save you money as you won't need as many live reads.

If you choose to include caching too take a look at these [caching strategies](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonElastiCache/latest/mem-ug/Strategies.html) to work out how you would want to use it.

Comment: Hi. I just checked. It seems that read replica + primary x4large would be much cheaper than  1 x12xlarge from what I can tell. How much EC would cost? Woudl it be cheaper then read replica?

Comment: It would be `$155.52` per month  for a single R5.large node which includes `13.07GB` of memory :)